# Oozie shell work flow

Tags: shell, hadoop, hdfs, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am trying to write a simple shell action in oozie which will copy the files from remote to hdfs.But I am getting error.

Here is my work flow.xml

```
<workflow-app name="WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
<start to="sshAction"/>
<action name="sshAction">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <exec>/user/root5/Oozie/Workflow/WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs/uploadFile.sh</exec>
        <file>/user/root5/Oozie/Workflow/WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs/uploadFile.sh#upload    File.sh</file>
      <capture-output/>
</shell>
<ok to="end" />
    <error to="killAction"/>
</action>
<kill name="killAction">
    <message>"Killed job due to error"</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

My uploadFile.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash -e

hadoop fs -copyFromLocal    /home/root5/Desktop/Avinash_sampleData/DataFolder/Data_04-05-2016 /user/root5/Oozie/DataFolder
```

My job.properties is

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8021
queueName=default

oozie.libpath=${nameNode}/user/root/oozie-workflows/lib
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes=true

oozieProjectRoot=${nameNode}/user/root5/Oozie
appPath=${oozieProjectRoot}/Workflow/WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs
oozie.wf.application.path=${appPath}

#inputDir=${oozieProjectRoot}/data
focusNodeLogin=root@localhost
```

And the stack trace in oozie is

```
2016-05-04 16:09:36,023  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[root5] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs] JOB[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2016-05-04 16:09:36,023  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[root5] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs] JOB[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2016-05-04 16:09:36,023  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[root5] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs] JOB[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2016-05-04 16:09:36,209  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[root5] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs] JOB[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@sshAction] Start action [0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@sshAction] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2016-05-04 16:09:36,353  WARN ShellActionExecutor:542 - USER[root5] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs] JOB[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@sshAction] credentials is null for the action
2016-05-04 16:09:37,441  INFO ShellActionExecutor:539 - USER[root5] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs] JOB[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@sshAction] checking action, external ID [job_201604251732_0160] status [RUNNING]
2016-05-04 16:09:37,544  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[root5] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs] JOB[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@sshAction] [***0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@sshAction***]Action status=RUNNING
2016-05-04 16:09:37,544  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[root5] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs] JOB[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@sshAction] [***0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@sshAction***]Action updated in DB!
2016-05-04 16:09:53,082  INFO CallbackServlet:539 - USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@sshAction] callback for action [0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@sshAction]
2016-05-04 16:09:53,317  INFO ShellActionExecutor:539 - USER[root5] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs] JOB[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@sshAction] action completed, external ID [job_201604251732_0160]
2016-05-04 16:09:53,346  WARN ShellActionExecutor:542 - USER[root5] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs] JOB[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@sshAction] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]
2016-05-04 16:09:53,576  INFO ActionEndXCommand:539 - USER[root5] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs] JOB[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@sshAction] ERROR is considered as FAILED for SLA
2016-05-04 16:09:53,754  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[root5] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs] JOB[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@killAction] Start action [0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@killAction] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2016-05-04 16:09:53,755  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[root5] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs] JOB[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@killAction] [***0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@killAction***]Action status=DONE
2016-05-04 16:09:53,755  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[root5] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs] JOB[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@killAction] [***0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@killAction***]Action updated in DB!
2016-05-04 16:09:53,943  WARN CoordActionUpdateXCommand:542 - USER[root5] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs] JOB[0000012-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[-] E1100: Command precondition does not hold before execution, [, coord action is null], Error Code: E1100
```

Please help me as in proceeding further.

```
Hive-workflow.xml
<workflow-app name="WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
<start to="hive-node"/>
<action name="hive-node">
    <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
       <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <job-xml>hive-site.xml</job-xml>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>default</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>oozie.hive.defaults</name>
                <value>hive-site.xml</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <script>Hive_script.hql</script>
    </hive>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="killAction"/>
</action>
<kill name="killAction">
    <message>"Hive failed, error   message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]"</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
And the Hive_script.hql
.# LOAD DATA inpath '/user/root5/Oozie/DataFolder/Data_04_05_2016.txt' INTO TABLE OOZIE_TABLE1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into a basic problem here. When you submit your Oozie workflow you never know on which node the workflow is executed. Therefore you should never reference your local filesystem in oozie.

What you can do instead:

- put the file into a hdfs path manually
- implement this path into your workflow
- let oozie copy the file from there

Also make sure you use the right hadoop shell commands for your installed version. I am used to something like hdfs dfs -put, but you may work on a different version.

Comment: You mean to say the script file /user/root5/Oozie/Workflow/WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs/uploadFile.sh should be placed in hdfs ?? If so, the path mentioned is hdfs path only.Also i have tried putting http://localhost:8020//user/root5/Oozie/Workflow/WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs/uploadFile.sh, both didn't work

Comment: What I am talking about is this line
`hadoop fs -copyFromLocal    /home/root5/Desktop/Avinash_sampleData/DataFolder/Data_04-05-2016 /user/root5/Oozie/DataFolder` in your upload.sh

I think you can not run such a line in a oozie job because oozie will not know which path on which local filesystem you mean. The file has to on the hdfs already.

Comment: Ok but I am trying to run the Hive Work flow action as well, it is also returning the simlar error.Instead of shellMain Launch error, it is throwing hiveMain Error.                                                                                                                         2016-05-05 11:44:34,880  WARN HiveActionExecutor:542 - USER[root5] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[WorkFlowCopyLocalTohdfs] JOB[0000029-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000029-160425173341619-oozie-oozi-W@hive-node] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code [40000]

Comment: Can you provide the code for that hive action? What Hive action do you want to run? What is happening there?

Comment: Added the Hive_script.hql and workflow.xml in the Question itself

Comment: the exit code is a different one (40000). You can check the oozie logs of the oozie job by using 'oozie logs' command.

If this does not bring up details you can check the hadoop logs which should track the job as well.